# ember js error: adding script tags in a view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

My ember js view looks like this:

```
//widget-blah.ember.hbs

<script class='X'
        {{bind-attr id='view.Y'}}
        {{bind-attr src='https://blah.com/blah.js'}}>
        </script>
```

This view is rendered correctly in a div I want. I can also see the script tag in DOM tree. But, the blah.js is not actually loaded by the browser.

How do I modify my view such that browser will load blah.js?

Comment: Why is it that you want to do this? I use use `didInsertElement` and load the script manually. `bind-attr` is also deprecated in 1.x, what version are you using?

Comment: Views are deprecated as well.